# Data binding between ng-bootstrap and component not working

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have implemented ng-bootstrap rating in my template as shown:

```
<div class="row m-t-2">
   <div class="col">
   <h5>Review Rating</h5>
   <div>
     <!-- <a (click)="filterProducts()">  -->
     <ngb-rating [(rate)]="reviewRating" max="5">
       <ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
         <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100">&#9733;</span>
       </ng-template>
     </ngb-rating>
     <!-- </a> -->
     <p>Please choose a rating</p>
     reviewRating {{reviewRating}}
   </div>
```

The object is to filter all products based on the rating that is selected. I wish to call the filterProducts() function of my component using the selected rating value. I have tried enclosing the ngb-rating segment of code in a link as shown in the commented-out segment of code in the template above but that does not work.

I have tried using the the life-cycle function, ngOnChanges as shown below but it is never invoked when the value of the rating changes in the template.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('changes ', changes);
    for (let propName in changes) {
      let chng = changes[propName];
      let cur = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
      let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
      console.log(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
    }
}
```

How do I detect changes to the rating value selected in the template from within the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-bootstrap Rating component emits a [`rateChange`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/api) event when the selected rating changes, with the new rating as the `$event` value. See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcuqtv) for a demo.

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="reviewRating" max="5" (rateChange)="onRateChange($event)">
  ...
</ngb-rating>
```

```
onRateChange(event: number) {
  console.log("The selected rate changed to", event);
}
```